# How do I create a 3D helical sine wave in Solidworks?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks

I'm trying to place this blue helical sine wave around the helix (which I already thickened) that is wrapped around an ellipsoid but I just can't make it work. What I'm trying to create is that body which I have created first but with wavy grooves along the outer edges of the helix.

I created the helix using the helix command with a variable pitch (pitch & revolution). Then I created the helical sine wave using equation driven curve command. All I've done so far is change the parametric equations randomly because I'm bad at calculus. Also, I have to follow an equation but it is explicit and not parametric but this plot of the parametric equation almost looks exactly what it should be.

I have just started using Solidworks last week so I'm not that familiar yet with most of the commands and features. I hope someone can give me an idea on how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following equations

- X(t) = 2* t* cos(3*t)
- y(t) = 2* t* sin(3*t)
- z(t)= 4 *t

You can change the parameters in the above equations.

More specifically Changing the:

- 2s and the 3s in the first two will change the rate that the circle of the  helix grows
- 4 will change the spacing of the helix